# hitTest.RowIndex is always -1

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

In project there is a DataGridView.

I have a little bit of code that I which displays information based on
the cell that was clicked.

My problem is how to detect if the user clicked on a column or row
header (anything other than a cell).

All this is tied to the 'dataGridView1_CellMouseDown' method, and I'm using
the HitTest to attempt to detect what the user clicked, but all I'm
getting is 'TopLeftHeader' when the user clicks a cell and 'None'
everywhere else and the Row index always comes as -1

Answer (score 2):

Using the `CellMouseDown` event gives you coordinates relative to the *cell* that was clicked.

Use the control's `MouseDown` event instead, which will give you control-based coordinates.

See [the example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the CellMouseDown event handler. In fact i find it a bit cleaner because with MouseDown event, you have to create a HitTest to get the selected row.

The following code is equivalent:

```
    private void dgv_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // If right-click
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Get selected row
            var selectedRow = dgvBatches.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        }
    }

    private void dgv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // If right-click
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Get the selected row/column
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dgvBatches.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            // Get selected row
            var selectedRow = dgvBatches.Rows[info.RowIndex];
        }
    }
```